# How to get category of a code-point?

Tags: c#, unicode

The `CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(string, int)` method gets the category of a code-point in a string, but I want to pass the code-point directly (an `int`).

The `Char.GetUnicodeCategory(char)` method only gets the category of a character in range U+FFFF-U+00.

I need something like `Char.GetUnicodeCategory(int)` for the range U+10FFFF-U+00, for efficiency. Suggestions?

Comment: `char.GetUnicodeCategory` which returns `UnicodeCategory` enum?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko It's the same as `CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(char)`, so won't solve my issue.  :/

Comment: char.GetUnicodeCategory("\U00010000", 0)

Comment: @HansPassant Didn't know C# brought C++'s unicode escape.

Comment: Looks like this is what you need - but it's internal: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/ff440aaee646319417522c11b34ab4fb668f4894/src/mscorlib/shared/System/Globalization/CharUnicodeInfo.cs#L293

Comment: How often do you see non-BMP characters? I'd be tempted to use `CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(char)` for any BMP-value, and take the hit of constructing a string and calling `GetUnicodeCategory(string, int)` for non-BMP characters. Or create your own lookup table...

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm using Mono, so I think that distinguising the BMP and suppl. plane characters will be the way. I've a similiar trick for validating ActionScript identifiers... I have 2 methods for validating the most common ASCII characters and the two resting methods are just for the messy characters I've never used. PS., I've already used UnicodeSet tool for this too (w/o using the CLI) and wrote a script for creating a binary pattern of categories.

Comment: I'm not sure what running on Mono has to do with it, unless you're saying that `GetUnicodeCategory(string, int)` isn't available on Mono?

Comment: @JonSkeet What I meant by using Mono is that the VS internals may be different. Thanks for your BMP tip, though. I even think it's the answer.